# Experience with gel-filled junction boxes

Tags: humidity, environmental-sealing

A lost answer to one of my questions mentioned gel-filling junction boxes for moisture protection. Has anybody worked with this technique before?

I am particularly interested in how difficult it is to remove the gel to change the connection.

The promotional video of the GUROSIL self-healing gel suggests that liquid gel will ooze out if one removes the gel? Is this really the case?

Regarding the products I have found "GUROSIL" and "Spelsberg Abox GT". Can anybody recommend an alternative they find better?

Comment: Perhaps this qualifies as a shopping recommendation request, which is frowned upon a bit.

Comment: you might consider silicone sealant

Comment: @Richman Silione gels exist in an extremely wide variety. Quite likely there is something that would be ok. However, the standard silicone sealant is probably too viscous to fill a box properly and probably next to impossible to remove if cast as a solid block. What do you think?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I see it as a question regarding tradecraft. Of course any tradesman has to buy his tools at some point...

Comment: We've been using [icky-pick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icky-pick) in telecom for a very long time. For the copper at least, when connecting wire to wire we sometimes used [these guys](http://www.goldmine-elec-products.com/prodinfo.asp?number=G17981). Most fiber optic cables also have gel in them for moisture protection. It's not really a practice to flood cases with gel anymore because it's so messy. I think it's only really done for direct bury stuff anymore. What kind of junctions are you protecting?

Comment: @Samuel I am protecting electronics connections in an environment with a near 100% humidity, salty, warm environment. It is highly corrosive to all copper connections. Though gel-filling might be overkill especially if it is very messy.

Comment: @Samuel I love the pigtail connectors you linked. For anybody else who is interested in them, they are called "Scotchlok™ UY-Moisture Resistant Pigtail Connector"

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is an entire industry making what you want, so you would think it not too hard to find some solutions. But alas, it is quite difficult. The industry is geared toward large telecom companies with direct advertising to local telephone companies. I worked as a fiber optic tech for four years and have used quite a few different cases like what you're looking for, I'm assuming you're going for the smaller ones. For the most part, as I said, the cases don't get filled with a fluid gel. Most of them just seal incredibly well. The main players (as of six years ago, before I went back to school) were:

[Coyote Splice Enclosures](http://coyoteruntclosure.com/), from them I'd recommend [the runt](http://www.newtechindustries.com/products/8006671-Coyote-Runt-Fiber-Splice-Closure-Splice-Case.html), it's quick to assemble and I've seen them sitting in water without taking any. The hardest thing with these is the cable wrapping takes practice to get right.

[Tyco Splice Enclosures](http://us.telecomosp.com/fiber%20optic%20products/fiber%20closures/default.htm), they now go by TE, the "A" enclosure from [their 450 series](http://www.te.com/en/industries/telecom-networks/browse-products/fiber-infrastructure/closures/fosc-450-overview.html) is a pretty awesome little dome. Fewer bolts and the entire cable entry gets a big sticky gel ring that seals it up tight. The cables just snap into the end plate and you screw two discs together to make the gel ring squish out around the cables and the dome, sealing them at the same time. They also make a nice line of [copper enclosures](http://us.telecomosp.com/copper%20products/copper%20closures/default.htm) (some that can be [direct buried](http://us.telecomosp.com/copper%20products/copper%20closures/certisealburied.htm)), which I have much less experience with.

The cases you've linked to seem quite nice too. They do look quite a bit less expensive, but messier. I can't comment on their effectiveness, but I do know a properly built fiber enclosure won't leak. The down side is the cost and the fact that you're not doing fiber in them, so the trays and other accessories likely won't be useful. Keep in mind many of these cases were designed for telecom manholes which, at least whenever I needed to get into them, were completely full of water.

As for acquiring these cases, try asking your local telephone company or look up some local fiber splicers, they might be willing to sell you some at their bulk rate.

I hope this helps. I'd be interested to see what you come up with.

-Samuel